# WSO2 Integration Studio Netsuite connector change authentication

Tags: wso2, netsuite, connector

I am trying to use the Netsuite connector in WSO2, currently it authorizes with email and password. My Netsuite account is a high-priviledged account as I need to access information about Sales Orders and Customers. When I try to use the connector, it gives a response saying I need two-factor authentication. Is there any way to edit the connector so it authorizes with a bearer token? This way I don't need TFA.

I have tried editing the XML files of the connector's init.xml file to take in the access token but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the connector, I created my own SOAP payload and used the tokenPassport object for authentication which I discovered thanks to @ycr :) now my Netsuite integration is working properly

Answer (score 0):

At the moment the Email and the password is send as a SOAP Header as in [here](https://github.com/wso2-extensions/esb-connector-netsuite/blob/master/src/main/resources/netsuite-create/addList.xml#L45). You will have to figure out how to send the Bearer token and then change the Payload accordingly.

Comment: Do you know if changing <email> and <password> to <Authorization> would work? I already know how to get the bearer token, I'm just confused about what to change the connector tags to so I can use the token. Should <email>email</email> and <password>pass</password> change to <Authorization>Bearer (token)</Authorization>?

Comment: @Karsten You may have to find that in the Netsuit API documentation. Take a look at this https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_N3445710.html#Authentication-for-SOAP-Web-Services

Comment: Hi,
I wasn't able to get the connector working, however I switched to using SOAP instead of REST, and I used the tokenPassport object that I found from your link :) now netsuite is cooperating, thanks!